# Knockout is undefined when installing via Package Installer

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, knockout.js, bower, visual-studio-2017

I installed Package Installer from Mads Kristensen, then installed git and bower via command so it can use both of them. I installed Knockout via "Quick Install Package" from the Package installer I mentioned above in my project. I have the following js:

```
// This is a simple *viewmodel* - JavaScript that defines the data and behavior of your UI
function AppViewModel() {
    this.firstName = "Bert";
    this.lastName = "Bertington";
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

(As you can see is the tutorial)

And I have the following in my view:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
    <script src="~/js/Index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div> 
        <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
        <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is an empty MVC web solution the folder structure is a classic empty MVC with a HomeController an Index ActionResult that returns the Index View.

The error is the following:
**Unhandled exception at line 8, column 1 in http://localhost:60689/js/Index.js
0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'ko' is undefined**

This is the first time Im using Git, Bower and Knockout so maybe Im making a mistake.

Comment: did you reference `knockout.js` lib? where ?

Comment: you are right, it lacked the reference, Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked why and this is what I discovered.

Bower does not install the distributable files in your conventional "Script" or "js" folder in your project, it is a hidden folder called: bower_components\knockout\dist\knockout.js

It will look like this:

```
<script src="~/bower_components/knockout/dist/knockout.js"></script>
```

In order to see them, go to the solution explorer and press the "Show All Files".